# Converting AS3 code from mouse to ios Touch event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

I have written some code to start off my game, i now want to change the controls from mouse to touch event so i can use it on my ipad.

the code below is how far i have got but i can't work out how to change it to work with touch and drag

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode
    import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
    import Box2D.Collision.*;
    import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
    import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
    import Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var world:b2World;
        private var worldScale:Number = 30;
        private var mouseJoint:b2MouseJoint;
        Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;       

        var myBlock:Array = new Array(
            new Block(),
            new Block(),
            new Block()
        );



        public function Main() {

            addChild(myBlock[0]);
            addChild(myBlock[1]);
            addChild(myBlock[2]);



            world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0,9.81),true);
            debugDraw();
            var bodyDef:b2BodyDef=new b2BodyDef();
            bodyDef.position.Set(320/worldScale,470/worldScale);

            var polygonShape:b2PolygonShape=new b2PolygonShape();
            polygonShape.SetAsBox(320/worldScale,10/worldScale);

            var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef=new b2FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.friction = 1;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5;
            fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;
            var groundBody:b2Body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
            groundBody.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);

            for (var i:int=0; i<3; i++) {
                createBox(Math.random()*500+70,400,b2Body.b2_dynamicBody);
                var targetBox:TargetBox=new TargetBox();
                addChild(targetBox);
                targetBox.x = 220 + i * 100;
                targetBox.y = 180;
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateWorld);

            stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, createJoint); 
        }
        private function createBox(pX:Number,pY:Number,type:int):void {
            var bodyDef:b2BodyDef=new b2BodyDef();
            bodyDef.position.Set(pX/worldScale,pY/worldScale);
            bodyDef.type = type;
            var polygonShape:b2PolygonShape=new b2PolygonShape();
            polygonShape.SetAsBox(30/worldScale,30/worldScale);
            var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef=new b2FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;
            fixtureDef.density = 1;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.2;
            var box:b2Body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
            box.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);
        }
        private function createJoint(e:TouchEvent):void {
            world.QueryPoint(queryCallback,mouseToWorld());
        }
        private function queryCallback(fixture:b2Fixture):Boolean {
            var touchedBody:b2Body = fixture.GetBody();
            if (touchedBody.GetType() == b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {
                var jointDef:b2MouseJointDef=new b2MouseJointDef();
                jointDef.bodyA = world.GetGroundBody();
                jointDef.bodyB = touchedBody;
                jointDef.target = mouseToWorld();
                jointDef.maxForce = 1000 * touchedBody.GetMass();
                mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(jointDef) as b2MouseJoint;
                stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, moveJoint);


                stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, finish); 
                stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,killJoint);
            }
            return false;
        }
        private function moveJoint(e:TouchEvent):void {
            mouseJoint.SetTarget(mouseToWorld());
        }
        private function killJoint(e:TouchEvent):void {
            world.DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
            mouseJoint = null;
            stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,moveJoint);
            stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,killJoint);
            stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,finish);

        }
        private function mouseToWorld():b2Vec2 {
            return new b2Vec2(mouseX/worldScale,mouseY/worldScale);
        }
        private function debugDraw():void {
            var debugDraw:b2DebugDraw=new b2DebugDraw();
            var debugSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
            addChild(debugSprite);
            debugDraw.SetSprite(debugSprite);
            debugDraw.SetDrawScale(worldScale);
            debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit|b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
            debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
            world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
        }
        private function finish(e:TouchEvent):void {
            for (var b:b2Body=world.GetBodyList(); b; b=b.GetNext()) {
                for (var i:int=0; i<3; i++) {
                    var distX:Number = b.GetPosition().x * worldScale - (220 + i * 100);
                    var distY:Number = b.GetPosition().y * worldScale - 180;

                    if (distX*distX+distY*distY<900 && b.GetType()==b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {

                    world.DestroyBody(b);
                    createBox(220 + i * 100,180,b2Body.b2_staticBody);
                    }   

                }
            }


        }

        private function updateWorld(e:Event):void {
            world.Step(1/30,10,10);
            world.ClearForces();

                var m=0;
                for (var b:b2Body=world.GetBodyList(); b; b=b.GetNext()) {
                    if (m==3) {m=0;}
                    var distX:Number = b.GetPosition().x * worldScale - (220 + m * 100);
                    var distY:Number = b.GetPosition().y * worldScale - 180;

                    if (b.GetType()==b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {
                        myBlock[m].x = distX + (220 + m * 100);
                        myBlock[m].y = distY + 180;
                        myBlock[m].rotation = b.GetAngle() * 180 / Math.PI;

                    }

                    m++
                }

            world.DrawDebugData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, how isn't it working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: In addition to @LondonDrugs_MediaServices questions I'd suggest looking at if you really need touch instead of mouse. Mouse events trigger on touch just fine on iPad and other devices and have the advantage that they also work fine on non-touch platforms. The only advantage touch events give you is that they offer multitouch support, but that is really not needed a lot of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All standard cursor and mouse events should translate to touchscreens. The obstacle is when you start using multitouch, but skimming through your code, it doesn't yet look like you have anything that's actually calling for multitouch data yet. Im not sure if the box2d libs require multitouch support as opposed to regular mouse events, but your errors could likely be coming from those libraries calling a "touch" related variable that may or may not be created yet, depending on where you are in your game. Are you in fact concerned with multi-support and what exactly are the errors you're getting?